# Refresh pivot for some sheets fails

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I want to refresh some pivots in excel which has many pivots in the workbook. Say sheet A & B has pivots and want to refresh the same -

Pls let me knwo if the below is correct - I am getting an error "Invalid use of property"

```vb
Sub Refreshsomepivot()

    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vSheets As Worksheets
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    vSheets = Array("A, B")
    For Each vSheet In vSheets
        MsgBox (vSheet.name)
            For Each pt In Sheets(vSheet).PivotTables
                pt.RefreshTable
            Next pt
    Next vSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `vSheet` doesn't have a `Name` property.   If that's not the problem line then you need to tell us which line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing Worksheets and Worksheet names. Your Array is meant to be an array of worksheet names, not an array of worksheets (`Worksheets`, btw, is a `Collection`, not an array).
Furthermore, your array is not an array of 2 elements, it's has only one element as your comma in withing the string - it needs to be `Array("A", "B")`

On more point you need to know is that `Array` returns an array of `Variant`, not `String`, therefore you need to declare it as such. If you loop over such an array, the "running" variable needs be be declared also as Variant.

Have a look to the following code:

```
Dim vSheetNames() As Variant, vSheetName As Variant

vSheetNames = Array("A", "B")
For Each vSheetName In vSheetNames
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Set vSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheetName)
    MsgBox vSheet.Name
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In vSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have this error below -

Comment: at line - "pt.RefreshTable " ----Application defined error or object defined error.

Comment: Check (with the debugger) which worksheet and which PivotTable throws that error. Can you refresh it manually in Excel?

Comment: Yes,  I did it manually. There is an error in the 1st loop it reads the correct worksheet but when it goes to the line pt.refreshtable I get that error.

Comment: ok , i am sorry - it completes the first loop but the values do not get refreshed from the data source. the second loop have this problem.

Comment: I forgot to tell something - the data source is a connection to an external file. I tried pt.update. It completed the loop but the value did not update. how do i get this updated?

Comment: I guess you are asking a second question here. Your original question was about your syntax problem (and I tried to answer that). Your question now is why one of your pivot table throws an error when you issue a `RefreshTable` - that's a complete different story. **I cannot answer this** and I think you should ask a **new question**, giving more details of the nature of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw , that code works for a sample data.